# What is the difference between "engage" and "deploy"？

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

These two words can both mean making sth ready for use. I've seen lots of usage like "Sword deployed", "We're being deployed", "Weapons system engaged", "Evac pod engaged", etc. in the movie *The Pacific Rim*.

There has to be kind of overlap in meaning, but I wonder if a certain difference exists.

Comment: Deploy is preparatory. You put something in the correct position to be used. Engage is much closer to activation, typically with a concrete target.

Comment: Can you plz elaborate on this a little more? Better using the examples I gave. Thx! @CodesInChaos

Comment: Somehow I think the opposite (but I might be wrong, I didn't see the movie yet). *Sword deployed* makes me think that the sword is now used. (If the sword is a missile, then it should have already been fired.) *X engaged* makes me think that the X is ready to use. (If it is a missile, then the system is now ready to fire, but the missile hasn't been launched yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Engage*** has a wide range of more or less connected meanings. You can engage an employee (give him employment), engage a gear (make it active), or be engaged to marry (pledged), etc.

The underlying senses of *engage* involve *commit, pledge, become involved with, attach*, deriving from the rare/archaic/obsolete...

> gage: *Something of value deposited to ensure the performance of some action, and liable to forfeiture in case of non-performance; a pawn, pledge, security.*

---

***Deploy*** derives from Latin *displicāre (to unfold)*. Originally this was only normally used of *military forces, troops*, in the sense of *to open out so as to form a more extended front or line*.

By lately, particularly with reference to *mechanically-activated weapons systems*, the two terms have both been increasingly used in the sense of *employ, **use***. It's a bit fanciful to say they actually *mean* anything different in OP's context, but if Captain Kirk on the [Starship Enterprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapons_in_Star_Trek) were to issue the orders...

> 1: *"**Engage** photon torpedoes!"*
>    or
>    2: *"**Deploy** photon torpedoes!"*

...the first could be interpreted as an instruction to *prepare* the torpedoes for use, and the second as an instruction to actually *fire* them. The words are used so loosely that in the above context, they're really synonyms - but if you ask *"In what sequence would Captain Kirk give these orders?"* ([a loaded question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152513/2637), implying there *must* be a difference), I suspect the vast majority of native speakers would say *"**1** then **2**".*

Comment: I don't know... in current usage, if you are ordered "Deploy your weapon, soldier!" that would mean to get it ready, not to fire. It depends on what weapon system you're talking about too. If you "deploy" an airplane, what does that mean?